# convert custom string to date format - PySpark

Tags: pyspark, type-conversion

Looking for a logic to convert custom string to date.
It is possible to convert the standard format (2023-01-20) easily using,

```
df.select(to_date(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('dt'))
```

But wanted to convert below string to date,

```
8/8/23, 8:08 AM
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below one to get the result -

```
df.select(to_timestamp(df.datetime, 'M/d/yy, h:mm a').alias('dt'))
```

Refer datetime patterns here -
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html